# Thread not completing properly, preventing application close

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, exit, winhttp

I'm writing a win32 form application and drawing it with Direct2D. I have a few cross threaded functions to do animations on it and I'm doing web requests with WinHTTP. The issue is, when I use any WinHttp functions (even just opening an HINTERNET session), it will cause the thread not to terminate properly. After I run the 'login' process once, the program cannot exit calmly. I've posted the relevant code below:

```
//the login process
void __cdecl processloginasync(void* arg)
{
    //getting text from textboxes, etc.

    if(usernamestr.find(L'@') != wstring::npos && usernamestr.find(L".") != wstring::npos) {
        swapdrawmode(1);
        _beginthread(loadwheel,NULL,arg);

        void* result = NULL;
        unsigned sz = 0;
        int rescode = web_request(L"appurl.mywebsite.com/func.php",ss.str().c_str(),result,sz);
        //other code to handle the reply...
        swapdrawmode(0);
    }
    else {
        error_str = L"Invalid email address.";
        err = TRUE;
    }

    if(err == TRUE) {
        textopacity = 0;
        animatemode = 0;
        _beginthread(animatetext,NULL,arg);
    }
    //I realize I haven't called 'free' on result, I'll fix that.
}

//the web_request function
int web_request (const wchar_t* server, const wchar_t* object, void*& dest, unsigned& size)
{
    vector<void*> retval;
    vector<unsigned> szs;
    HINTERNET hSess = NULL, hConn = NULL, hReq = NULL;
    int res = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD retcode = NULL;
    short err = FALSE;

    const wchar_t* accepted_types[] = {
        L"image/*",
        L"text/*",
        NULL
    };

    hSess = WinHttpOpen(L"smartCARS2 Web/1.1",WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
    if(hSess)
        hConn = WinHttpConnect(hSess,server,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL);
    else {
        err = TRUE;
        retcode = HTTP_OPEN_FAILED;
    }
    if(hConn)
        hReq = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConn, NULL, object, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,accepted_types,NULL);
    else {
        err = TRUE;
        retcode = HTTP_CONN_FAILED;
    }
    if(hReq)
        res = WinHttpSendRequest(hReq, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    else {
        err = TRUE;
        retcode = HTTP_OPENREQ_FAILED;
    }
    if(res)
        res = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hReq, NULL);
    else {
        err = TRUE;
        retcode = HTTP_SEND_REQ_FAILED;
    }

    DWORD tsize = 0;
    if(res) {
        do {
            dwSize = 0;
            if(!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hReq, &dwSize)) {
                retcode = HTTP_COULD_NOT_QUERY_SIZE;
                err = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            if(!dwSize)
                break;
            tsize += dwSize;
            void* rets = malloc(dwSize + 1);
            if(!rets) {
                break;
            }
            if(!WinHttpReadData(hReq, (void*)rets, dwSize,  &dwDownloaded)) {
                retcode = HTTP_COULD_NOT_READ_DATA;
                err = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            if(!dwDownloaded)  {
                retcode =  HTTP_COULD_NOT_DOWNLOAD;
                err = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            szs.push_back(dwSize);
            retval.push_back(rets);

        } while(dwSize > 0);
    }
    size = tsize;
    unsigned int sz = retval.size();
    dest = malloc(tsize);
    tsize = 0;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        memcpy((BYTE*)dest + tsize,retval[i],szs[i]);
        free(retval[i]);
        tsize += szs[i];
    }
    if(hSess)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSess);
    if(hConn)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConn);
    if(hReq)
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hReq);
    if(err == TRUE)
        return retcode;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Following your code is a bit difficult.  Can you define what you mean by terminating calmly?

Comment: I apologize for that, I posted a lot because I'm only partially sure where the issue resides. I mean that if you close the program (by clicking the X), despite the threads having seemed to end (they do not trigger breakpoints in their proc), the process continues running.

Comment: You may also consider whether `animatetext` and `loadwheel` are properly being shutdown as well. None of these threads seem to be waited on for proper completion. I'd consider using `_beginthreadex()` to get a valid wait-able handle and `WaitForSingleObject()` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` in the appropriate places in you code.

Comment: Like @Codeguard answers, find out what is preventing the exit of your main thread - the one with the main window that receives the WM_CLOSE message.

Comment: The WndProc receives WM_CLOSE and posts the exit message. The 'main' function also returns 0, although the zombie process continues.

Comment: OK, what's left..  static dtors?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, as soon as the main thread terminates, the others are not waited for. So the problem is probably in your main thread. You just need to attach a debugger if not already being debugged (Debug | Attach to process in VS) to a zombie process and press "Break all", then use "Threads" and "Call stack" windows to figure what's happening.

Comment: This makes sense, however, I tested without creating any threads at all and the issue persisted, only caused by a call to any WinHTTP functions. The Break All does show several threads, but none of them are directly user created.

Comment: I've found that calling 'exit(0);' at the end of main causes it to terminate, but I question whether or not that's good practice.

Comment: From what you say, I think you have a problem in one of global destructors. Please copy the stack of the main thread (you can for example find it by ID, remembering it at start) in the zombie process.

Comment: The main thread returns 0 and ends, as do the subsequent animation threads. There are no user-created running, they are all something like '_NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory@16' and only exist once a WinHTTP call is made (my dtors are fine).

Comment: I think you should try to reduce your application as much as you can, while the problem still exists.